# Contact Form PHP - send from specific email

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I have a Contact form on my website, works fine. Issue comes about when the contact form is sent to my email, it goes into my spam folder because the email the form is sent from is a random email address.

Is there a way to send the form to my email using a trusted email address?

```
 <?php
    // Define some constants
    define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "Greg Collins" );
    define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "maxacollins@gmail.com" );


// Read the form values
$success = false;
$sendername = isset( $_POST['username'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['username'] ) : "";
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['email'] ) : "";
$senderSubject = isset( $_POST['subject'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['subject'] ) : "";
$message = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['message'] ) : "";

// If all values exist, send the email
if ( $sendername && $senderEmail && $senderSubject && $message) {
  $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
  $headers = " G.C. Environmental.com - Contact Form Message ";
  $msgBody = " 
  Name: " . $sendername . "
  From: " . $senderEmail . " <" . $senderSubject . ">
  Message: " . $message . "  
  ";
  $success = mail( $recipient, $headers, $msgBody );

  //Set Location After Successsfull Submission
  header('Location: contact.html?message=Successfull');
}

else{
    //Set Location After Unsuccesssfull Submission
    header('Location: index.html?message=Failed');  
}

?>
```

Comment: Configure out MTA, or ask your hoster.

Comment: You could look into using PHPMailer with gmail SMTP.